# MS Access Forms for updation and running macros

Tags: sql, ms-access

1. I am using MS Access 2007 and am a novice. I am good with SQL.
2. I have a form which has 6 text boxes say a1,a2...a6 which is for collecting inputs like [Week 1], [Week 25], [Week 76]....
3. I want to create a button which will update the text entered into the 6 text boxes into a table in access which I have already created. The table has an ID column (six cells - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) and a second column called week which needs to be updated with the data from the text boxes.
4. The button click must also run some kind of macro (I have never worked with macros before) which will compare and the text in the text boxes 1 and 6 and run one among the 4 queries based on the result. i.e if it is between week 1 and week 3 run QUERY_1, else if it between week 4 and week 6 run QUERY_2.
5. Can anyone please guide me with this?

Comment: Your question the way it stands is too broad.  You will have to make an attempt yourself first and when you have more specific question, then ask those.

Comment: can you please provide me a link wherein I can learn the above concept?

Comment: Agree that question is too broad. You will not be learning a concept but a set of tools including form design and automation. Here is a hint: Forget "macro" and do your learning in "vba". If you are coming from PHP, everything will be very different -- but overall, much less to learn.

Comment: Your question has several pieces.  Try searching stackoverflow using the tags [**vba and ms-access**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba+ms-access).  There are several questions/answers that may help piece together what you are looking for.  Also, you could purchase a Microsoft Access VBA programming book.